# Digits in a four digit number

Tags: probability

Can some one help me solve this problem:
How many digits are required to form a number plate of four digits till 7000?
The ans is:36

Comment: Your Question is unclear.  By "till 7000" do you mean the number of different (license) plates that should be possible?

Comment: Can you explain the question a bit better??

Comment: Till 7000 means upto 7000 so I mean from 1000-7000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guess as to how the answer 36 might be derived.

The 4 digit numbers "till 7000" are from 1000 to 6999.

To form that range of numbers we can use six digits in the leading position, 1-6, and ten digits in each of the three less significant positions, 0-9.

Altogether this involves 6 + 3*10 = 36 digits.

Comment: Tanq.That seems to be the only explanation available...